# gtsave() causes a bus error due to 'invalid alignment' on a raspberry pi 4 model b with 4 GB ram

Tags: r, gt, bus-error

This short R program creates the error:

```
library(gt)

# Create a simple data frame
data <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
  Age = c(25, 30, 22),
  Score = c(85, 92, 78)
)

# Create a gt table
gt_table <- gt(data)

sessioninfo::session_info()
# Save the table to a file
gtsave(gt_table, filename = "table.html")
```

works fine under windows but not on linux sessioninfo is:

```
setting  value  
version  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)  
os       Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)  
system   aarch64, linux-gnu  
ui       X11  
language en_US.UTF-8  
collate  en_US.UTF-8  
ctype    en_US.UTF-8  
tz       Europe/Luxembourg  
date     2023-07-26  
pandoc   2.9.2.1 @ /usr/bin/pandoc
```

and packages:

```
package     \* version date (UTC) lib source
cli           3.6.1   2023-03-23   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
digest        0.6.33  2023-07-07   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
dplyr         1.1.2   2023-04-20   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
fansi         1.0.4   2023-01-22   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
fastmap       1.1.1   2023-02-24   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
generics      0.1.3   2022-07-05   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
gt          \* 0.9.0   2023-03-31   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
htmltools     0.5.5   2023-03-23   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
pillar        1.9.0   2023-03-22   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
rlang         1.1.1   2023-04-28   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
tibble        3.2.1   2023-03-20   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
tidyselect    1.2.0   2022-10-10   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
utf8          1.2.3   2023-01-31   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
vctrs         0.6.3   2023-06-14   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
xml2          1.3.5   2023-07-06   CRAN (R 4.2.2)
```

detailed error:

```
\*\*\* caught bus error \*\*\*
address 0xf44a0b0b, cause 'invalid alignment'
```

Traceback:

```
1: rlang::hash(add_sass_file_mtime(list(x, get_package_version("sass"))))
2: sass_hash(list(discard_dependencies(input), options, cache_key_extra,     if (isTRUE(write_attachments)) get_file_mtimes(file_attachments)))
3: sass::sass(list(list(element_id = id), as.list(stats::setNames(gt_options_tbl$value,     gt_options_tbl$parameter)), sass::sass_file(system_file(file = "css/gt_colors.scss")),     sass::sass_file(system_file(file = "css/gt_styles_default.scss")),     glue::glue(.open = "\<\<", .close = "\>\>", "\\n        \<\<ifelse(has_id, '##{$element_id} table', '.gt_table')\>\> {\\n          \<\<font_family_attr\>\>\\n          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;\\n          -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;\\n        }\\n\\n        \<\<ifelse(has_id, '##{$element_id} {', '')\>\>\\n        @include gt_styles();\\n        \<\<ifelse(has_id, '}', '')\>\>\\n\\n        \<\<ifelse(has_additional_css, table_additional_css, '')\>\>\\n        ")))
4: compile_scss(data = x, id = id)
5: as.tags.gt_tbl(data)
6: htmltools::as.tags(data)
7: gt_save_html(data = data, filename, path, ...)
8: gtsave(gt_table, filename = "table.html")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

It normally creates an html file that contains a simple table.
As said , no problems under windows with the same sessioninfo output!?